# Get serverURL inside app module within Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am getting the error Http urls has to be absolute. It's because iam using this `http.get('/env')` the app is ran in different environments so the urls can change. So I can't use this for example `http.get('http://test.com/env')` I also cant use window.location.origin. bacause I am using universal. How do I solve this?

```
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';

providers: [
    RootController,
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    HttpRequestService,
    {
      'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
      'useFactory': (http: Http) => {
        return () => {

          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const req = http.get('/env').pipe(map(env => env.json())).subscribe(config => {
              CONFIG.ORIGIN = config.ORIGIN;
              CONFIG.API_URL = config.API_URL;
              CONFIG.BASE_HREF = config.BASE_HREF;
              CONFIG.SOCIAL = config.SOCIAL;

              console.log(CONFIG);

              resolve(CONFIG);
            }, error => {
              reject(error);
            });
          });
        };
      },
      'deps': [Http],
      'multi': true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

server.ts

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';


// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Provide the URL from universal and use it angular side if it's specified

Comment: Can you explain more on how to do this

Comment: I posted a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

1. Provide the server url from the angular universal server

**server.ts**

**Edit** Here is the version using express engine

```
//...

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {

  //let serverUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
  let serverUrl = `http://localhost:${PORT}`;
  res.render('index', 
  { req, 
    res, 
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,

    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
        {
          provide: 'serverUrl',
          useValue: serverUrl
        }
    ]

    });
});
```

**End edit**

**server.ts**

(Without using express engine)

```
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
let serverUrl = options.req.protocol + '://' + options.req.get('host');

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    //...
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      {
        provide: 'serverUrl',
        useValue: serverUrl
      }
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    //...
  });
});
```

2. Use provided value angular side

**app.module.ts**

```
import {Optional, InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
const ServerUrl = new InjectionToken('serverUrl');


//...
providers: [
RootController,
AuthService,
AuthGuard,
HttpRequestService,
{
  'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
  'useFactory': (http: Http, serverUrl: string) => {
    return () => {

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         //serverUrl will be empty client side, and contain server URL when using angular universal
        const req = http.get((serverUrl || '') + '/env').pipe(map(env => env.json())).subscribe(config => {
          CONFIG.ORIGIN = config.ORIGIN;
          CONFIG.API_URL = config.API_URL;
          CONFIG.BASE_HREF = config.BASE_HREF;
          CONFIG.SOCIAL = config.SOCIAL;

          console.log(CONFIG);

          resolve(CONFIG);
        }, error => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });
    };
  },
  'deps': [Http, [new Optional(), ServerUrl] ], //<= optional dependency
  'multi': true
},
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Comment: How do you put it inside the app.engine like this: app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

Comment: I also get a "shadow named" linting issue in: 'useFactory': (http: HttpClient, ServerUrl: string). on the ServerURL

Comment: I edited my answer for the shadow variable. You can pass extra args like indicated tehre: https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine#request-based-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks but how do I implement the serverUrl code into the ngExpressEngine?

Comment: Like in the link I provided. If this is unclear, edit your question to add your server side code and I'll try to modify it

Comment: I added the server.ts code. Not sure how to make options works in the app.engine

Comment: Sorry, I meant your current code for **server.ts** (before trying to add my answer)

Comment: And you don't have any get routes?

Comment: I do I have added the whole server.ts file

Comment: I get this now cannot find options. const serverUrl = options.req.protocol + '://' + options.req.get('host');

Comment: I tried removing options and just use req but then i get this Error: URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute. URL: [object Object]/env

Comment: I don't know express engine, but req.get('host') may not work. I edited the way to retrieve the url server side to be more static. You know that it's going to be localhost anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176871/discussion-between-david-and-raymond-the-developer).