# Angular universal express server shows function url instead of entry url

Tags: angular, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

Help i need to get my custom domain to fetch store config but when I try to use the url on the server side is showing me the cloud function url, not the url that the user typed in.
example:
my user types in the browser https://test-url.mybuss.co/
Hosting redirects to functions (i.e. https://us-east1-blablabla.com/)
functions renders my html this includes making some http calls to my API BUT
I have two ways to recognize which company is trying to check my store

First one query params
https://test-url.mybuss.co/myStore
I sent myStore as a query parameter and success
second case
https://test-url.mybuss.co/
I sent the host url as a parameter and success
BUT whenever I'm on server side instead of sending this URL(https://test-url.mybuss.co/) the express server catches the cloud function url.
Any ideas?

I've tried every host parameter

```
console.log(req.headers.host);

console.log(req.hostname);

console.log(req.host); // even this deprecated one

console.log(req.subdomains)
```

and they all give me the same result
https://us-east1-blablabla.com/

Tried using platformLocation
and also tried this solution right here

```
req.get('host')
```

[get server url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518664/get-serverurl-inside-app-module-within-angular-universal/51525066#51525066)

Comment: Can you please try console.log(location.origin); and check if it works ?

Comment: location not defined imma try to get req req.headers.origin;

Comment: req.headers.origin came as undefined and location.origin doesn't exist

Comment: I think that req.get('x-forwarded-Host') has the info that I need.

Comment: If you already found a solution then can you please post it as an answer for visibility ?

Comment: not yet Cuz I'm having trouble passing it to my resolver. As soon as I'm really done/sure that I solved the problem i'll post the answer. Is that okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to my answer was using the parameter x-fowarded-Host
Which I obtained by req.get('x-forwarded-Host')
And transfered through providers

```
 res.render(indexHtml, {
      req, providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: req.get('x-forwarded-Host') },
      ]
    });
```

I also had to include these lines
app.server.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
  ],
```

app.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    BrowserTransferStateModule
],
```

to retrieve the data in my resolver I had to include this variable in my constructor

```
@Optional() @Inject('ORIGIN_URL') public urlOrigin: string
```